# net::ERR uploading files with Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, axios

I'm getting this error `POST http://localhost:8000/dashboard/laws/create net::ERR_FAILED` when I try to store a file into my laravel app using an axios request. I'm not sure why this is happening, so if anyone can help me please... :(

```
if ($request->validate(
            [
                'name' => 'required|string',
                'description' => 'required|string',
                'type' => 'required|in:nati,inter',
                'file' => 'required|mimetypes:application/pdf'
            ]
        )) {
            // Save the file
            $file = new LegalFile($request->except(['file']));

            // save file in the storage
            $file->setFilePath();
            $file->file_order = LegalFile::where('type', $file->type)->count();
            $file->save();
            $disk= Storage::disk('s3');
            $disk->put('files', file_get_contents($request->file('file')));

            return response('Archivo guardado exitosamente', 200);
        }
```

Comment: Look in the laravel logs to see whatś happen. And why you are using `file_get_contents($request->file('file'))` instead just `$request->file('file')`?

Comment: [Sat Feb 22 19:07:05 2020] 127.0.0.1:59029 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF) This is the error that appears in the console.

Comment: Unexpected EOF means “unexpected end of file”. Maybe you have some syntax error in your code?

Comment: But I can save another files. Some files throw the error and others does not.

Comment: You mean that with the same method you can save some files, but with others returns this error? In the validation I see that you only allow pdf files, so what is the difference between the files that you can save and those that you cannot. Is the file size?

Comment: Yeah, the size maybe a difference. I uploaded a file of 1,471KB and I have a file of 365KB that I cannot upload.